# Elaborated type refers to a typedef error on Clang

Tags: c++, clang

I am getting the following error using this compiler Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)

Code is here

test.h

```
  class media
  {
  public:
     typedef enum
     {
       audio,
       video,
       text,
       data
     }mediatype;
  };
```

test.cpp

```
 #include "test.h"

 int main()
 {
   enum media::mediatype medias[] = {media::audio, media::video};
   for (int i=0; (i < sizeof(medias) / sizeof(enum media::mediatype)); ++i)
   {


   }
 }
```

test.cpp:5:15: error: elaborated type refers to a typedef
  enum media::mediatype medias[] = {media::audio, media::video};

test.cpp:6:58: error: reference to 'mediatype' is ambiguous
  for (int i=0; (i < sizeof(medias) / sizeof(enum media::mediatype)); ++i)

If I remove the enum keyword as follows the code compiles

```
  #include "test.h"

  int main()
  {
   media::mediatype medias[] = {media::audio, media::video};
   for (int i=0; (i < sizeof(medias) / sizeof(media::mediatype)); ++i)
   {


   }
 }
```

Can someone say why clang is complaining

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the message say exactly what's wrong? And why on earth are you typedefing the enum in the first place?!

Comment: The `mediatype` enumeration is not a member that you can take the size of. If you want to know how many enumerations there are in a specific `enum`, there is a hack to add one extra enumeration whose value is the number of enumerations there is.

Comment: the definition of that enum in that header is from existing library so I'm not typedef'ing that

Comment: Your compiler supports C++11. There is absolutely no need for old sizeof tricks when you can do `for(auto& m : medias) { }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you do not need to use `typedef` with `enum`s: when you write `enum XYZ`, compilers creates a type `XYZ`, so you can later write `XYZ varOfTypeXYZ`, as opposed to `enum XYZ varOfTypeXYZ`.

Rewriting `media` as follows will fix the problem:

```
class media {
public:
     enum mediatype
     {
       audio,
       video,
       text,
       data
     };
};
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/BZAi4u)

The problem with writing `enum media::mediatype` is that your declaration does not create an `enum` tag `mediatype`, it creates a type called `mediatype`. The `enum` that you define is anonymous, so the reference `enum media::mediatype` cannot be resolved properly.

Therefore, another way to fix this problem is to add a tag to `enum` definition, like this:

```
class media {
public:
     typedef enum mediatype
     {
       audio,
       video,
       text,
       data
     } mediatype;
};
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/Eh8z5J)

Answer (score 1):

Change to :

```
class media {
public:
  enum mediatype {audio, video, text, data};
};


int main()
 {
   media::mediatype medias[] = {media::audio, media::video};
   for (int i=0; (i < sizeof(medias) / sizeof(enum media::mediatype)); ++i) {

   }
 }
```

It's not Clang's fault what you are writing isn't valid C++ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The `typedef` means that `mediatype` is a type name, but not an enumeration name; so `enum media::mediatype` is not a valid way to refer to it. It can only be referred to as `media::mediatype`.

If you change it to the more usual idiom:

```
enum mediatype {...};
```

then it's both a type name and an enumeration name, so you can refer to it as either `enum media::mediatype`, or just `media::mediatype`.

Within a `sizeof` expression, you could also refer to an object rather than a typename, which is slightly less error-prone since you'll still get the correct answer if the array type changes:

```
sizeof(medias) / sizeof(medias[0])
```

Better still, you could use a helper function to give the size of an array, which is even less error-prone, since you don't have to duplicate the array name, and it won't give an incorrect result if you accidentally apply it to a pointer rather than an array:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t array_size(T(&)[N]) {return N;}

for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size(medias); ++i) {}
```

or, in C++11, you don't need to calculate the size at all:

```
for (media::mediatype media : medias) {}
```